# regular expression http in python

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a long text and I would like to obtain all the entries in the text that match the following pattern:

http************.id.txt, where * could be any entry (unknown length), and the dots are actually dots in the text.  I'd like to have a list with all the entries that match such pattern.

One of the many tries was,

```
c = re.match(r'^(http)(.*)id.txt', b)
```

I also tried,

```
c = re.findall(r'(http)(.*)fastq.gz', b)
```

but none of them give a list of http*****.fastq.gz entries.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"

Comment: I mean it does not give me the list i want.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you could be a bit more precise where you're saying that * could be "any entry."  Perhaps it could be any number of non-whitespace characters (r'(http\S*)' for example?  Or it might be any number of any character other than certain bits of punctuation (r'http[^.,; \t\n]*' for example).  Be more specific about how you'd know that you've hit the end of one of these strings and then figure out how to represent that as a regular expression atom.

Comment: @JimDennis you are completely right, however i needed a fast solution and the ones they provided ended up solving my problem.  But in general it's quite a sloppy definition the one I said, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)?

```
import re

b = 'http://match.id.txt --- blablabla --- http://match2.id.txt'
matches = re.findall(r'http.*?\.id\.txt', b)
print matches  # ['http://match.id.txt', 'http://match2.id.txt']
```

The `?` just after the `.*` reduce the matching to the minimum (without it, it matches the whole string, with `.* = match.id.txt --- blablabla --- http://match2`). See some tutorial about regex to know more about it.

**[Demo available here](http://ideone.com/HE8EhQ)**

Comment: I tried it as well, but it does not give me the list as you mentioned

Comment: nice, thanks!  Still doesn't work for my text since it has a lot more odd character, trying to figure out what's specific about my text

Comment: Why don't you just share with us a bit of your text?

Answer (score 0):

You may scape your dot characters with the character '\', because .(dot) is the regex for any character
Example:

```
c = re.match(r'^(http).*(\.*)id\.txt', b)
```